# Where can I store user details from a database so I can pull the information on every page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When a user logins, I want to be able to store all his profile information so I can display, for example, his email on different pages of my website, but I don't want to have to keep querying the database for every time I want to display his email.  How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to work with either Cache (via `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache`), or put it in the session or cookie.

Cache is by far the best method, cookie causes extra bandwidth, and session has its own line of cons.

Comment: However is Cache not available to the entire application? Meaning you would have to write your own mechanism for getting the correct data you want to ensure you don't actually return someone else's email address. Personally I think Session is best suited to this.

Comment: You are right, but sessions timeout, sessions don't scale very nice etc etc. Poor-mans cache would just use for example Cache["user-" + myid.ToString()]

Answer (score 1):

You can use asp.net session variables to store user profile information and display those details from the session variable on different pages.